# sessions in multiple tomcats

Tags: session, tomcat

How do I make multiple tomcats on different servers sharing sessions?
I have a balancer sitting in front of 2 tomcat on two different servers, so when user starts a session, it's only associated with one of the tomcats. He might or might not get the session in the next request.

Comment: Which load balancer do you use ? Figure out if you can configure sticky sessions on it.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can tell it to do sticky sessions, so the LB keeps requests from a client on one app server...

edit --

[Difference between session affinity and sticky session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1040025/difference-between-session-affinity-and-sticky-session)