# Difference between ingress and service's kubernetes session affinity

Tags: kubernetes, service, nginx-ingress, session-affinity

What are the differences between using an [nginx ingress with the session affinity annotations](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/affinity/cookie/) (as below example) and a [service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#configuration) with the `service.spec.sessionAffinity` set to `ClientIP`.

From what I understand, [both reach the same goal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1040025/3840700) but I wonder if there are some differences other than the primer being done at ingress level with a cookie while second operates at the service level using the clients IP. Also, would that be a bad idea to use both a the same time ?

And last question, If I want to enable sticky session **between pods within the cluster**, would the `service.spec.sessionAffinity: ClientIP` definition would be enough to ensure a backend pod connects everytime to the same database pod ?

**Ingress example :**

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: cookie
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity-mode: persistent
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-change-on-failure: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-expires: "172800"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-max-age: "172800"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-name: STICKY_SESSION
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "false"
```

**From the Kubernetes' service [API documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.22/#servicespec-v1-core) :**

> **sessionAffinity** :
> Supports "ClientIP" and "None". Used to maintain session affinity.
> Enable client IP based session affinity. Must be ClientIP or None.
> Defaults to None. More info:
> https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#virtual-ips-and-service-proxies